# How can I add loading ONLY to the clicked button in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There is a table which loops and outputs the data which comes from API. I have added a button inside the table. When you click it, it should send the id of the clicked button and till it recieves the data of the function which needs to be printed, it should be in loading. Here is my code.

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>{{$t('message.numberReport')}}</th>
    <th>{{$t('message.periodFrom')}}</th>
    <th>{{$t('message.periodTo')}}</th>
    <th>{{$t('message.printButton')}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(item,index) in getReportInfo" :key="index">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.periodFrom }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.periodTo }}</td>
    <td>
      <v-btn
        class="primary"
        :loading="loading"
        :disabled="loading"
        @click="fetchGetReportDetailed(item)"
      >{{ $t('message.printButton')}}</v-btn>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But when I clicked the particular button, all the buttons are getting in loaded mode. How do I fix it? Any suggestion would be deeply appreciated.[here is the visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUYtN.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Using `index` of item in list.

You can register a new variable in your data for example `indexClicked` .

```
data () {
    return {
        // Some predefined value, 0 isn't good because index can be 0.
        indexClicked: undefined // Some predefined value
    }
}
```

And when you click at button you can send `index` value:

```
<td>
<v-btn class="primary"
       :loading="loading && indexClicked === index" 
       :disabled="loading && indexClicked === index" 
       @click="fetchGetReportDetailed(item, index)">
       {{ $t('message.printButton') }}
</v-btn>
</td>
```

And in your `fetchGetReportDetailed(item, index)` method you need to assign `index` to `this.indexClicked` like:

```
fetchGetReportDetailed (item, index) {
    // Your code
    this.indexClicked = index;
}
```

This should work. But if you need more information please provide more code.

**Note** if you have a problem with multiple conditions in `:disable` you can create a method which will return true or false depends on condition `loading  && this.indexClicked === index`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You're using a single data property for all rows, so in mounted hook add a property called `loading` to each row like :

```
mounted(){
   this.getReportInfo=this.getReportInfo.map(rep=>{
               rep.loading=false;
             return rep;
         });
}
```

and the template do:

```
   <tr v-for="(item,index) in getReportInfo" :key="index">
                            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.periodFrom }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.periodTo }}</td>
                            <td><v-btn  class="primary" :loading="item.loading" :disabled="loading"  @click="fetchGetReportDetailed(item,index)" >{{ $t('message.printButton')}}</v-btn></td>
                        </tr>
```

in `fetchGetReportDetailed` method :

```
fetchGetReportDetailed(item,index){

....

this.getReportInfo[index].loading=true;
this.$set(this.getReportInfo,index,this.getReportInfo[index])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could separate the `tr` that is displaying the data into its own state-full component and call the function from within the component.

This way the state of loading for each item in the array will be local to its own component.

Comment: I don't understand, why this solution is less voted. But definitely it's the proper and clear one from an architecture perspective. Just devide everything, what is inside of the table to the sub-components and you won't face this issue.